# event for change of value via developer tools

Tags: javascript, jquery

Is there any event triggered when we change the value of input using developer tools?.

I have tried using `change()`, `blur()`, `focus()`. But these events are not triggered if we change the values via developer tools.

Comment: I think mutationobserver might do something but unless you manually trigger the change, it won't update

Answer (score 0):

It seems that even with the MutationObserver-API this is not possible. If you manipulate the value of the input via console directly, the mutation doesn't trigger.

The other possibility I just tried wasn't helpful either: With the Developer-Tools opened, right-click on the input and choosing "Break On -> Attributes Change". But this isn't working, too.

I'll think a little - right now it seems it's not working easily...

---

*First answer:*

You should look into the [MutationObserver-API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver) if you are not trying to support old browsers. Taking the example there as a starting point, you could try something like this:

```
// select the target node
var target = document.querySelector('#your-input');

function mutationCallback(mutation) {
  /*
    Your logic here
  */
}

// create an observer instance
var observer = new MutationObserver(function(mutations) {
  mutations.forEach(mutationCallback);    
});

// configuration of the observer:
var config = { attributes: true, childList: true };

// pass in the target node, as well as the observer options
observer.observe(target, config);
```